# Adding tags and styles when rendering templates in Adobe Contribute CS5

Tags: html, tags, flash-cs5, adobe-contribute

I have several templates that have been created with Adobe Dreamweaver CS5. If I create pages based on those templates via Dreamweaver, they render perfectly. They also rendered perfectly in pages created using Adobe Contribute CS4.

However, my users have upgraded to Contribute CS5, and strangely Contribute is adding tags to the rendered page, in un-editable sections of the page.

For example, in the template the following code:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<ul id="topnav">
    <li>
        <a href="/index.html" class="nav_home"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="../about/index.html" class="nav_about">About us</a>
        <div class="sub">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../about/team.html">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="../about/invest.html">Investors</a></li>

...etc
```

renders exactly the same when used to create a page in Dreamweaver, but is changed by Contribute CS5 to this:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<ul id="topnav" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <li>
        <a href="/index.html" class="nav_home"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="../../about/index.html" class="nav_about">About us</a>
        <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="sub">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0">
                <li><a href="../../about/team.html">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../about/invest.html">Investors</a></li>
```

Notice the addition of the two **`<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>`** tags, as well as the addition of **`style="margin-bottom: 0"`** to the `<ul>` tag.

Is this a known issue of Contribute? If so, how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: they should just re-brand it as `Adobe CodeMangler`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your paragraph setting in the site administration dialog.

Refer to ["Paragraph Spacing Options in Adobe Contribute"](http://blogs.adobe.com/contribute/2010/06/paragraph_spacing_options_in_a.html).